# Optional group not being captured

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

I got an huge roll of records I need to turn into a table, like this:

```
********************
alwaysThere1=09/2019
alwaysThere2=987456
bunch of stuff 
i dont need
optional=698,00
more stuff i dont need
********************
alwaysThere1=06/2019
alwaysThere2=123658
bunch of stuff 
more stuff 
********************
alwaysThere1=09/2019
alwaysThere2=987699
bunch of stuff
optional=9999,00
stuff more stuff
```

I'm able to capture the first two groups, but not the third, that may or may not exist, using the following regex:

```
^[\*].+?alwaysThere1=(\d\d\/\d\d\d\d).+?alwaysThere2=(\d{6}).+?((:?optional=)[\d,]+)?[^\*]+
```

I want to get something like this:

```
09/2019;987456;698,00
06/2019;123658;
09/2019;987699;9999,00
```

However, using the replace pattern `\1;\2;\4\n` on Notepad++ I`m only getting this:

```
09/2019;987456;
06/2019;123658;
09/2019;987699;
```

Why I can't capture the optional group? The pattern seems to match the whole record, without going over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 3 capturing groups and use those in the replacement. To prevent overmatching you could make use of repeating groups and a negative lookahead to make sure that the string does not start with only `*`.

As there are parts which are always there you could first match those on the first 2 lines.

```
^\*+\R.*=(\d+/\d{4})\R.*=(\d{6})(?:\R(?!(?:.*=\d+,\d+|\*+)$).*)*(?:\R.*=(\d+,\d+))?(?:\R(?!\*+$).*)*
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `\*+` Match 1+ times `*`
- `\R.*=` Unicode newline sequence, match until the last `=`
- `(\d{2}/\d{4})` Capture **group 1** match 2 digits `/` 4 digits
- `\R.*=` Unicode newline sequence, match until the last `=`
- `(\d{6})` Capture **group 2** match 6 digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\R(?!(?:.*=\d+,\d+|\*+)$).*` Match line that do not contain only `*` or pattern `=\d+,\d+`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to match all those lines
- `(?:\R.*=(\d+,\d+))?` Optionally match the line that does contain pattern `=\d+,\d+` and capture digits comma digits in **group 3**
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\R(?!\*+$).*` Match line that does not contain `*` only
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to match all those lines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kssYzD/1)

`$1;$2;$3`

Output

```
09/2019;987456;698,00
06/2019;123658;
09/2019;987699;9999,00
```